# file transfer using UDP protocol

Tags: c, udp

I have a server and client code which I am using to transfer file from server to client. After compiling, instead of copying my whole file from server directory to client directory, it shows the content of file on the terminal. I am new to c and this my assignment. I know UDP is not the best possible way to implement file transfer application. But this is how I have to do it.

This is server side:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

#define IP_PROTOCOL 0 
#define PORT_NO 15050 
#define NET_BUF_SIZE 32 
#define cipherKey 'S' 
#define sendrecvflag 0 
#define nofile "File Not Found!" 

// funtion to clear buffer 
void clearBuf(char* b) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < NET_BUF_SIZE; i++) 
        b[i] = '\0'; 
} 

// funtion to encrypt 
char Cipher(char ch) 
{ 
    return ch ^ cipherKey; 
} 

// funtion sending file 
int sendFile(FILE* fp, char* buf, int s) 
{ 
    int i, len; 
    if (fp == NULL) { 
        strcpy(buf, nofile); 
        len = strlen(nofile); 
        buf[len] = EOF; 
        for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) 
            buf[i] = Cipher(buf[i]); 
        return 1; 
    } 

    char ch, ch2; 
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) { 
        ch = fgetc(fp); 
        ch2 = Cipher(ch); 
        buf[i] = ch2; 
        if (ch == EOF) 
            return 1; 
    } 
    return 0; 
} 

// driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, nBytes; 
    struct sockaddr_in addr_con; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr_con); 
    addr_con.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    addr_con.sin_port = htons(PORT_NO); 
    addr_con.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    char net_buf[NET_BUF_SIZE]; 
    FILE* fp; 

    // socket() 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IP_PROTOCOL); 

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        printf("\nfile descriptor not received!!\n"); 
    else
        printf("\nfile descriptor %d received\n", sockfd); 

    // bind() 
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_con, sizeof(addr_con)) == 0) 
        printf("\nSuccessfully binded!\n"); 
    else
        printf("\nBinding Failed!\n"); 

    while (1) { 
        printf("\nWaiting for file name...\n"); 

        // receive file name 
        clearBuf(net_buf); 

        nBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, net_buf, 
                          NET_BUF_SIZE, sendrecvflag, 
                          (struct sockaddr*)&addr_con, &addrlen); 

        fp = fopen(net_buf, "r"); 
        printf("\nFile Name Received: %s\n", net_buf); 
        if (fp == NULL) 
            printf("\nFile open failed!\n"); 
        else
            printf("\nFile Successfully opened!\n"); 

        while (1) { 
            if (sendFile(fp, net_buf, NET_BUF_SIZE)) { 
                sendto(sockfd, net_buf, NET_BUF_SIZE, 
                       sendrecvflag,  
                    (struct sockaddr*)&addr_con, addrlen); 
                break; 
            } 

            // send 
            sendto(sockfd, net_buf, NET_BUF_SIZE, 
                   sendrecvflag, 
                (struct sockaddr*)&addr_con, addrlen); 
            clearBuf(net_buf); 
        } 
        if (fp != NULL) 
            fclose(fp); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

This is client side:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

#define IP_PROTOCOL 0 
#define IP_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1" // localhost 
#define PORT_NO 15050 
#define NET_BUF_SIZE 32 
#define cipherKey 'S' 
#define sendrecvflag 0 

// funtion to clear buffer 
void clearBuf(char* b) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < NET_BUF_SIZE; i++) 
        b[i] = '\0'; 
} 

// function for decryption 
char Cipher(char ch) 
{ 
    return ch ^ cipherKey; 
} 

// function to receive file 
int recvFile(char* buf, int s) 
{ 
    int i; 
    char ch; 
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) { 
        ch = buf[i]; 
        ch = Cipher(ch); 
        if (ch == EOF) 
            return 1; 
        else
            printf("%c", ch); 
    } 
    return 0; 
} 

// driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, nBytes; 
    struct sockaddr_in addr_con; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr_con); 
    addr_con.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    addr_con.sin_port = htons(PORT_NO); 
    addr_con.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_ADDRESS); 
    char net_buf[NET_BUF_SIZE]; 
    FILE* fp; 

    // socket() 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IP_PROTOCOL); 

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        printf("\nfile descriptor not received!!\n"); 
    else
        printf("\nfile descriptor %d received\n", sockfd); 

    while (1) { 
        printf("\nPlease enter file name to receive:\n"); 
        scanf("%s", net_buf); 
        sendto(sockfd, net_buf, NET_BUF_SIZE, sendrecvflag, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_con, addrlen); 

        printf("\n---------Data Received---------\n"); 

        while (1) { 
            // receive 
            clearBuf(net_buf); 
            nBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, net_buf, NET_BUF_SIZE, sendrecvflag, (struct sockaddr*)&addr_con, &addrlen); 

            // process 
            if (recvFile(net_buf, NET_BUF_SIZE)) { 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        printf("\n-------------------------------\n"); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

I need to copy file from Server to Client

Comment: You read file content in your server and send it, so basically you will receive your file content in your client. If you want the file, you have to write the received content to a new file in the client.

Comment: Is there any reason you just can't write the bytes to a file in `recvFile()` rather than outputting to the screen with `printf()`?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Your use of EOF is dubious - it's usually an int, and truncating to char causes problems.  Your code has strlen(), can it transfer only text files?